# One click of the submit button in form_for results in 3 items in my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a form in my rails app that creates an item in my database, but when I submit the form, it creates 3 items per click.

I have 2 other forms that add things to the same database, but they are on different pages, could that be related?

This is my form on the "new debate" page:

```
<%= form_for(@debate) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :proposition %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :proposition %>
   </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I also have another form on the "show debate" page that appears twice:

```
<%= form_for(@debate.debates.create) do |support_form| %>
  <div>
    <%= support_form.label :content %><br />
    <%= support_form.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <%= support_form.hidden_field :is_supporting, :value => is_supporting %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= support_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And when I click on the submit button on any of the 3 forms, I get 3 new debates.

Comment: In your first view, what are you setting `@debate` to? Also, do all the 3 newly created `Debate` objects have the same attributes?

Comment: @debate is a new debate. The debate objects do not have the same attributes, the first one has the properties I give it in the form, and the rest have nil as all their properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code, might be creating those extra records.

```
= form_for(@debate.debates.create) do |support_form|
```

If my assumption is correct `.debates` is an association, and you are creating that association with that line.

Try using `build`

```
= form_for(@debate.debates.build) do |support_form|
```

Comment: OK it doesn't actually work perfectly. When I use create, the debate_id of the new debate is correctly set to @debate, but when I use build, the debate_id of the new debate is nil.

Comment: in the 2nd form `@debate`, is that a new record or an existing record?

Comment: Well, I guess that doesn't matter really, but what I gather from the views you sent, `@debate` would already exist and you are trying to create an association for `debates`. So `@debate` should be an existing record. If `@debate` is a new record, you will actually have a form more like the first one then use a `fields_for` to then provide fields for the associated `debates`. You may want to look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1